# What is a center of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have tried to search the definition of it up on Google, but the explanations of center of gravity were very confusing and I had trouble understanding them. Can you explain to me what center of gravity is in a very simple way that I can understand.

Answer (score 1):

The center of gravity of a rigid body is the *centroid* of its mass.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Basically, it's the weighted average position of all of the mass in the body.  That is to say, if you scale the position vector of each particle by the mass of the particle, and then compute the average all of the resulting vectors, you'll get the center of gravity.

In classical mechanics, if none of the bodies in a problem is allowed to rotate, then you can solve most problems by assuming that all of the mass of each body is concentrated in a single point at the body's center of gravity.

Comment: So its where the weight of the body is centered at.

Comment: Better to say, it's where you can _pretend_ the weight is centered in order to solve certain problems.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to james large's answer, you can also see the center of gravity as the intersection of all the vertical lines when you hang your solid by any point.

[image]

(link from http://www.splung.com)